# add function to saving change on Options Pages

Tags: plugins, forms, admin-menu, options

i make page like this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Creating_Options_Pages&oldid=97268#See_It_All_Together_2)
and it work fine but i need to run some script after it like editing a file

i was add it to

```
function my_function() {
    //do something
}
function register_mysettings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
    my_function();
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
```

but it load every time (without submit!)
please help. thx

Comment: There several actions/filters associated with options that can be used for different purposes. What is your exact need? Run `my_function()` after the options are upaded or before?

Comment: i need to run the function after update. because my_function() need to use those options. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a task after a option has been updated, you can use [`updated_option` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_option/):

```
add_action( 'updated_option', 'updated_option_callback', 10, 3 );
function updated_option_callback( $option, $old_value, $value ) {
     //Do something
}
```

Also, you can use [`update_option_{option-name}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_option_option/) specifically for each option. For example:

```
add_action( 'update_option_new_option_name', 'update_new_option_name_callback', 10, 2 );
function update_new_option_name_callback( $old_value, $value ) {
     //Do something
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, these actions won't fire if the changes are made via the default WordPress GUI.